# Antd Select - how to show different value in the dropdown and Input field

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

**Current UI**

[image]

**Expected Behaviour**
[image]

How can I do it?

App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { Select } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

const countryNames = [
  {
    name: "Japan",
    code: "+987"
  },
  {
    name: "aVeryVeryVeryVeryLongCountryName",
    code: "+123"
  }
];

const handleChange = (value: string) => {
  console.log(`selected ${value}`);
};

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <>
    <Select defaultValue="Japan" onChange={handleChange}>
      {countryNames.map((country) => (
        <Option key={country.name} value={country.name}>
          {`${country.code} ${country.name}`}
        </Option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </>
);

export default App;
```

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-5-1-5-forked-mfw8fj?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `antd` [document](https://ant.design/components/select), `Select` can specify a label value from a `Option` props with `optionLabelProp`, which in this use case can get value from `country.code`.

For extending size of `Option` based on its content, `dropdownMatchSelectWidth` can be set `false`, so that the `Option` is not limited to the size of `Select`.

Modified demo on: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-5-1-5-forked-hlsyb2?file=/demo.tsx)

```
<Select
  defaultValue="Japan"
  onChange={handleChange}
  //  Specify label prop here
  optionLabelProp="label"
  //  Set Option to be extendable by content here
  dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}
>
  {countryNames.map((country) => (
    <Option
      key={country.name}
      value={country.name}
      //  Give label value for Select here
      label={country.code}
    >
      {`${country.code} ${country.name}`}
    </Option>
  ))}
</Select>
```